# BuddyPress group creation broken at "Settings" step

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

BuddyPress version: 1.9.2
Wordpress version: 3.8.1

I have a very angry client at the moment.

The buddy press installation has been functioning flawlessly for a couple of weeks until the last few days.

When creating a new group, at the second step (Settings) the usual options of “Public/Private” etc do not show. When clicking “Next Step” button you get the WordPress error page of “Are you sure you want to do this?”

Have tried disabling all plugins and still not working so I’ve ruled out a plugin issue.

**UPDATE:**

Going to try move to a fresh server and reinstall piece by piece. Will report back.

Comment: Sometimes the "Are you sure you want to do this?" message is associated with a failed WordPress nonce check. Have you made any customisations to the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the installation to a fresh server and all is good now. I suspect it was something to do with the Varnish config I was running.